# Detect youtube time then show DIV? using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

Hi I was wondering if you could detect the time on a embeded(iframe) youtube video and then if it is at the right time show a DIV.
example: (I know this will not be like the code at all):

```
If (time == 28)
{
$('#Stage_Rectangle').show();
}
```

Anyway here is what I am trying to do I have a video that plays once and then when the video ends it redirects the url using `window.location.href` How ever at the end of the video the youtube play button pops up before the window redirects I'm basically trying to get rid of the play button that pops up by hiding it with a div so yeah my thought was detecting 28 seconds (the video is 29 seconds) and then showing the div to hide the button.

Is it possible ? and how would I go about it ?

Thank you In advance for any advice !

Answer (score 0):

```
ytplayer = document.getElementById("movie_player");
ytplayer.getCurrentTime();
```

[HERE IS THE API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html)

Comment: people are like crazy .. do not event care to comment while downgrading .. go get a life

Comment: Thanks for the reply can I use player.getCurrentTime(); and then set a var up like var TheTime = player.getCurrentTime(); ? then implement it into a if statement ? or would there be a better way?